# Как реализовать смену изображения без перезагрузки веб страницы?

Tags: php, html, css

Изучаю PHP, решил реализовать простенькую галерею. Все работает как хочется пока картинок немного :) но если их под сотню то возникают траблы. На странице, вместо меню картинки, вместо контента тоже изображение. При клике по картинке в меню, изображение должно меняться, но без перезагрузки самой страницы.

Как это реализовать используя только PHP?

Досконально можно не объяснять, просто примерное направление, дальше я сам!

Comment: JavaScript. Нужно начать с него

Comment: Не обязательно использовать AJAX. Можно подготовить специальный php файл, в котором будет генерироваться изображение. При клике на изображение, выполняем JS: `document.getElementById('изображение').src = '/get_image.php?rid='+Math.random();`

Comment: @stashappy неплохой подход, за такой ответ я бы проголосовал)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ @StasHappy:

Создайте на сервере PHP скрипт, который будет выдавать адрес на нужную картинку в зависимости от переданного GET параметра. Например, так:

```
$img = $_GET['image'];
echo 'URL картинки';
```

Допустим, назовем этот скрипт `get_image.php`.

При клике на изображение выполняйте код `Javascript`:

```
document.getElementById('изображение').src = '/get_image.php?image='+Math.random();
```

Answer (score -1):

Это можно реализовать через `ajax`, на `ajax` можно загружать контент без перезагрузки страницы. Например: кликаем на картинку в меню, через `ajax` передаются данные (какие именно данные нужно загрузить) обработчику на php и обработанные данные возвращаются на страничку в заданный блок без перезагрузки страницы.

Comment: AJAX использовть совершенно незачем. Решение @Stas намного лучше, поскольку работает на чистом HTML + JS. Кстати, ajax не даст загрузить картинку с другого домена, если это не разрешено им.

Comment: @DanielShatz Если ты знаешь лучшую реализацию данного вопрос дай свой ответ на этот вопрос. (здесь все могут давать ответы на вопросы ).